# Design options for updating table cells with asyncronous images

Tags: ios, coding-style

I am trying to find out what my options are for this problems in terms of code design.

I have a table view, each cell owns an instance of a data model. 
An asyncronous http request for json containing all text data for data model is made. This contains information about all cells. When it is retreived, all cells are created with their models.
However, this also includes a url to retreive an image from. Requests for an image for each cell are made asyncronously as they are being created / the table is being populated.

As the images come back, I need to update the UIImage views of the cells. What are my options with regard to doing this in a clean way?

Things I've considered:
pass along the UIImageView reference into completion block of image request method and update it when received. If model is later changed, view does not update itself :\
Subscribe the cell views to their models notifications about having changed. Feels very wrong, each cell would pick it up and have to check if it's their model that sent it?

Comment: There are a trillion examples of this across the web.  Pick one and go!  Here's a [favorite](http://www.hollance.com/2011/03/mhlazytableimages-efficiently-load-images-for-large-tables/).

Answer (score 0):

you can use any of the following

1. [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)
2. [HJCache](https://github.com/markofjohnson/HJCache)
3. [Three20](https://github.com/facebook/three20)

and many more..